# converting non-carrot xml to carrot xml

Tags: xslt

I am new to carrot and have very little knowledge on xsl, so please bear with me. my input file is an xml of search results from a database. it is not in carrot format so according to documentation I have to convert it to carrot format using an xsl file. I followed the sample xsl that carrot provides (for bbc news), but it does not find the title (atl), snippets (ab) and link (url) I specified (got return msg "Your query did not return any documents"). here are the files, and I would really appreciate it if anyone can help. thanks a million.

**xml (my 3 sample search records)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<records>
  <rec resultID="1">
    <header shortDbName="aph" longDbName="Academic Search Premier" uiTerm="43811908">
      <controlInfo>
        <bkinfo />
        <jinfo>
          <jtl>BMC Public Health</jtl>
          <issn>14712458</issn>
        </jinfo>
        <pubinfo>
          <dt year="2007" month="01" day="01">2007</dt>
          <vid>7</vid>
        </pubinfo>
        <artinfo>
          <ppf>31</ppf>
          <ppct>12</ppct>
          <formats>
            <fmt type="PDF" size="322KB" />
          </formats>
          <tig>
            <atl>Cocaine- and opiate-related fatal overdose in New York City, 1990-2000.</atl>
          </tig>
          <aug />
          <sug />
          <pubtype>Academic Journal</pubtype>
          <doctype>Article</doctype>
        </artinfo>
        <language code="eng">English</language>
      </controlInfo>
      <displayInfo>
        <pLink>
          <url>http://survey.hshsl.umaryland.edu/?url=http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&amp;db=aph&amp;AN=43811908&amp;site=eds-live</url>
        </pLink>
      </displayInfo>
    </header>
  </rec>
  <rec resultID="2">
    <header shortDbName="aph" longDbName="Academic Search Premier" uiTerm="43830400">
      <controlInfo>
        <bkinfo />
        <jinfo>
          <jtl>BMC Public Health</jtl>
          <issn>14712458</issn>
        </jinfo>
        <pubinfo>
          <dt year="2007" month="01" day="01">2007</dt>
          <vid>7</vid>
        </pubinfo>
        <artinfo>
          <ppf>31</ppf>
          <ppct>12</ppct>
          <formats>
            <fmt type="PDF" size="312KB" />
          </formats>
          <tig>
            <atl>Cocaine- and opiate-related fatal overdose in New York City, 1990--2000.</atl>
          </tig>
          <aug />
          <sug />
          <pubtype>Academic Journal</pubtype>
          <doctype>Article</doctype>
        </artinfo>
        <language code="eng">English</language>
      </controlInfo>
      <displayInfo>
        <pLink>
          <url>http://survey.hshsl.umaryland.edu/?url=http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&amp;db=aph&amp;AN=43830400&amp;site=eds-live</url>
        </pLink>
      </displayInfo>
    </header>
  </rec>
  <rec resultID="3">
    <header shortDbName="cmedm" longDbName="MEDLINE" uiTerm="17334938">
      <controlInfo>
        <bkinfo />
        <jinfo>
          <jtl>Journal Of Urban Health: Bulletin Of The New York Academy Of Medicine</jtl>
          <jtl>J Urban Health</jtl>
          <issn type="Print">1099-3460</issn>
        </jinfo>
        <pubinfo>
          <dt year="2007" month="03" day="01">2007 Mar</dt>
          <vid>84</vid>
          <iid>2</iid>
          <place>United States</place>
        </pubinfo>
        <artinfo>
          <ui type="pmid">17334938</ui>
          <pages>292-306</pages>
          <formats />
          <tig>
            <atl>Observed patterns of illicit opiate overdose deaths in Chicago, 1999-2003.</atl>
          </tig>
          <aug>
            <au>Scott G</au>
            <au>Thomas SD</au>
          <aug>
          <sug>
            <subj type="geographic">Chicago</subj>
            <subj type="major">Drug Overdose mortality</subj>
            <subj type="major">Narcotics poisoning</subj>
            <subj type="major">Opioid-Related Disorders mortality</subj>
            <subj type="minor">Age Factors</subj>
            <subj type="minor">Drug Overdose ethnology</subj>
            <subj type="minor">Opioid-Related Disorders epidemiology</subj>
            </sug>
          <ab>This article explores trends and correlates of Chicago's opiate-related overdose (OD) deaths. We manually examined data from every death certificate filed between 1999 and 2003 to identify all Chicago residents' accidental deaths involving acute intoxication with illicit opiates, OD, or opiate poisoning.</ab>
          <pubtype>Journal Article</pubtype>
        </artinfo>
        <language code="eng">English</language>
      </controlInfo>
      <displayInfo>
        <pLink>
          <url>http://survey.hshsl.umaryland.edu/?url=http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&amp;db=cmedm&amp;AN=17334938&amp;site=eds-live</url>
        </pLink>
      </displayInfo>
    </header>
  </rec>
</records>
```

**xsl (following carrot sample):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"
       media-type="application/xml" encoding="UTF-8" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <searchresult>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/reords/rec/header" />
    </searchresult>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="header">
    <document>
      <title><xsl:value-of select="atl" /></title>
      <snippet>
        <xsl:value-of select="ab" />
      </snippet>
      <url><xsl:value-of select="url" /></url>
    </document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is it just because you wrote `/reords/` instead of `/records/`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things off but you are really close.

As @G. Ken Holman points out in the comments, you have a typo in your `apply-templates`. It should read as

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/records/rec/header" />
```

Then the three elements that you reference in the header template don't exist at the places that you reference them. Below is the correct XPath for each one.

```
<xsl:value-of select="controlInfo/artinfo/tig/atl" />
<xsl:value-of select="displayInfo/pLink/url" />
<xsl:value-of select="controlInfo/artinfo/ab" />
```

Or if you don't want to list the whole path you can shortcut it.

```
<xsl:value-of select="//atl" />
<xsl:value-of select="//url" />
<xsl:value-of select="//ab" />
```

But that's not always recommended for large documents or one with an element name that can repeat.

After updating the paths I was able to get the following output:

```
<searchresult>
  <document>
    <title>Cocaine- and opiate-related fatal overdose in New York City, 1990-2000.</title>
    <snippet/>
    <url>http://survey.hshsl.umaryland.edu/?url=http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&amp;db=aph&amp;AN=43811908&amp;site=eds-live</url>
  </document>
  <document>
    <title>Cocaine- and opiate-related fatal overdose in New York City, 1990--2000.</title>
    <snippet/>
    <url>http://survey.hshsl.umaryland.edu/?url=http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&amp;db=aph&amp;AN=43830400&amp;site=eds-live</url>
  </document>
  <document>
    <title>Observed patterns of illicit opiate overdose deaths in Chicago, 1999-2003.</title>
    <snippet>This article explores trends and correlates of Chicago's opiate-related overdose (OD) deaths. We manually examined data from every death certificate filed between 1999 and 2003 to identify all Chicago residents' accidental deaths involving acute intoxication with illicit opiates, OD, or opiate poisoning.</snippet>
    <url>http://survey.hshsl.umaryland.edu/?url=http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&amp;db=cmedm&amp;AN=17334938&amp;site=eds-live</url>
  </document>
</searchresult>
```